# Connect Kubernetes cluster to RStudio

Tags: kubernetes, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is it possible to connect Kubernetes google cloud cluster with RStudio/RStudio Server? How?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, effort and caffeine.

Comment: Perhaps this?  https://docs.rstudio.com/rsp/integration/launcher-kubernetes/